# How to view recently client created records in django admin?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-admin

Is there any way to see recently added records as a notification in django admin? I googled but I didn't find any thing special. For example in your site you have Contacts page and each time you login to your admin panel you see notifications about new Contact model records?? Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you can use [django-admin-notifications](https://github.com/andybak/django-admin-notifications) module for that.

[Install](https://github.com/andybak/django-admin-notifications#installation) and [configure](https://github.com/andybak/django-admin-notifications#basic-usage) it for your project.

Then define a new `notifications.py` file in `Contacts` app like this:

```
import admin_notifications
from models import Contacts
def notification():
    count = Contacts.objects.filter(status=Contacts.STATUS_NEW).count()
    if count:
        return 'You have {} new contacts <a href="/admin/contacts/">message</a>'.format(count)
    else:
        return ''

admin_notifications.register(notification)
```

Comment: Should I create a NEW_STATUS field for that?

Comment: And what about turning off notifications after seeing them?

Comment: You can create a new `status` field as `CharField` for `Contacts` model with [choice](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.choices) option which have `STATUS_NEW`, `STATUS_READ` , `STATUS_ANSWERED` ,.. for that. And after you read or consider a message of `Contacts`, make it as  `STATUS_READ`.

Comment: Thanks I find what I want but first I think I should create a Boolean field with default value of 0. Then each time when I view the post I change the value of that Boolean field to True.